# How do I inititate the equivalent of a mobile phone USSD session from a web app?

Tags: web-applications, mobile, sms, ussd

There is a mobile money transfer service that I am trying to create a web app equivalent for so that I can make transfers from a web app. The way it currently works is as follows:

- User dials *125*000# from their mobile
- User is prompted for 4 digit pin
- After authentication, User is presented with menu options, one of which is "4. Send Money"
- User chooses 4 and is prompted for recipients number 
  -User enters recepient's number, total and the confirms the transaction and the amount is transferred.

So ideally, I want to have people open an online account which they can link to this already existing service. Then from the website, they can perform the transaction that has the same result as above. i.e. send money to a friend by entering their number and authenticating the transaction. So is this at all possible to replicate on a web app since the service is USSD based? How would I go about doing it? If I were to find an alternative to USSD but still operate consistently with their USSD server or app server but using a different technology, what would be the most ideal workaround? What information and access permission would I need to update and perform transaction operations from the host of the current app? Do any of the leading SMS APIs like Twilio have any possible influence on such an application?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to do that.

Authentication in that application is probably:

1. MSISDN (phone number)
2. 4 digit PIN.

You need both. So you basically need not only a phone number but also you need that number registered on the GSM network to talk to it through USSD.

Your best shot is visiting the company that owns the USSD application and see if they can provide an API you can use to use in your WEB PROJECT. You will need to be extremely careful about security though. A good way to enroll users with a phone number in a WebSite is using SMS confirmation codes. You could enroll your mobile users that way.

Answer (score 0):

Currently most USSD apps provide short codes.
In the East Africa region where mobile money is prevalent.
If you have money on your mobile money account, you can bypass the prompts to the exact point where you authorise transaction with PIN.

Example in Rwanda, (this should work for Kenya, Uganda), different codes though.
Rwanda's short code is *182$
To buy airtime from my wallet: I do this: `*182*2*1*1*200#`
Then authenticate on the next step with my PIN
To send mobile money from my wallet to another phone number **078xxxxxxx**.

```
*182*1*1*078xxxxxxx*200#
```

I think you could make a Phone link to it on your website using the HTML tel tag or Javascript.
Here is a sample one using [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/wr92uc3s/1/).
It is working on my end. One error, it appears the tel link reads the "#" as a terminator for the phone number.